# About Customs clearance in Vladivostok by DBSferry from Japan

Tags: customs-and-immigration, japan, russia, automobiles

A private car (TOYOTA Town Ace Van) will be transported to Vladivostok by DBS Ferry from Sakaiminato, Tottori Prefecture, Japan to Vladivostok.
The car will travel from Russia to the EU and take it home from the EU.

So can you tell me how to do customs procedures in Vladivostok? I don't understand Russian at all.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Would the car be transported (as cargo) in Europe, or you will use it for the travel? Possibly the sister site https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/ will help more, because this sort of transport should be more in their "daily" experiences.

Comment: @GiacomoCatanazzi Since the OP may be Japanese and travelling from Japan through Russia to the EU and back, this would be a travel topic.

Comment: Wow. You know you'll need to cross a few thousand km worth of distance without understanding Russian at all. 0_o

Answer (score 4):

You will need to fill two copies of ТД-6 (not a kaomoji) paper on entrance and two copies of same ТД-6 paper on exit. You can google for PDF. Of course it's in russian.

There is non-zero chance you get rejected without any reason, so you need to be prepared to do something in such case.

IMHO it would be more reliable if you do it through some company that has their people on both sides Japan and Russia. So you could talk personally in Japan and get help in Russia. Should be not that hard to find in Tottori. Maybe even DBS Ferry itself can help.